# How to include the OpenCL libraries to produce a stand alone application?

Tags: linux, linker, opencl

I tried to show a colleague the fancy stuff I can do with OpenCL, but the exec would not run on her computer. Some `libopencl.so` (or similar) files were missing (i.e. she did not have OpenCL installed). So my probably rather basic (Linux) question is, How do I include all the necessary `so` files that my little `C` + `OpenCL` program will also run on machines without OpenCL?

Comment: There is probably no way to do this, at least not in a way that is remotely portable or reliable. The target system must have OpenCL properly installed, because OpenCL can run on a multitude of different hardware components (and, heterogenously, too). It doesn't suffice to copy _some library_ around. Often, OpenCL comes as "bonus install" with display drivers. If that is not the case, your friend can, as a last resort, install the x86 software implementation freely available from AMD (search for stream SDK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Damon's comment already states, this is not possible to do in a general way, since each kind of device has its own vendor and that vendor has its own implementation of OpenCL. However, if what you want to do is simply to have a "portable" copy of your OpenCL application that will run on most Linux computers, there is a way to achieve that.

1. Download the AMD APP SDK (currently version 2.4). I'll be assuming its the 64-bit version but it should be pretty much identical for 32-bit or other version numbers, just change the corresponding strings.
2. Extract the SDK to a subdirectory of your applications executable. So for instance if the application is in $HOME/myapp, then the SDK files should be in $HOME/myapp/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.4-lnx64.
3. Extract the ICD files from the icd-registration.tgz archive into a folder named icd. So we should have $HOME/myapp/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.4-lnx64/icd/amdocl32.icd (and amdocl64.icd).

Now we have the workings of a portable installation of the AMD APP SDK, which should work on most x86-processors. We just need to set the appropriate environment variables before launching the application. Since I am not a GNU/Linux person and don't know bash very well I have hardcoded the path to our portable directory. Presumably it is somehow possible to get the current location automatically, which would obviously be much nicer.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=$HOME/myapp
export OPENCL_VENDOR_PATH=$DIRECTORY/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.4-lnx64/icd
export AMDAPPSDKROOT=$DIRECTORY/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.4-lnx64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AMDAPPSDKROOT/lib/x86_64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./myapp
```

The above script should be placed in the root directory of your application, i.e. $HOME/myapp/scriptname. Thus we can launch the portable application by doing ./scriptname. As I said since I don't know bash very well the above script could certainly be much nicer, handling arguments to the program and automatically figuring out the scripts location. But it should show the general idea of how to do this.

Comment: Hi Quantumboredom, thanks for making the effort. I develop on NVIDIA, but I will try to adapt your steps to the NVIDIA SDK.

Comment: I don't have an Nvidia card, however AFAIK Nvidia bundles the CUDA/OpenCL runtime components with their drivers, and since Nvidia's driver would have to be installed for OpenCL to function on an Nvidia GPU there's no way to do this portably. If you want the application to run on an Nvidia GPU then Nvidia's drivers must be installed normally. However an OpenCL application developed and compiled using Nvidia's OpenCL SDK should run on a portable solution like I described (but obviously using the CPU instead).